# Convert nvarchar with hex string to binary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

my table looks like this (all columns are nvarchar):

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
----------------------
|  ... | FFF8 | ...  |
|  ... |  -1  | ...  |
|  ... | FFF6 | ...  |
|  ... |  -9  | ...  |
```

If the value in the second column is not "-1" or "-9" i want to convert from hex to binary i. Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the data type?

Comment: datatype is nvarchar

Comment: and what you want to do if the value is -1 or -9?

Comment: What do you mean by binary? Do you mean a string like "110101001" or just a number?

Comment: yes, a string like "110101001" @AndrewMorton

Comment: @RadimBača, then i want to do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to that [link](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1378060-391-1.aspx)

It still uses replaces, but it look a bit nicer than previous answer:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HexToBinary] 
(
@hex varchar(200) 
)

RETURNS varchar(1000)

AS

BEGIN

SET @HEX=REPLACE (@HEX,'0','0000')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'1','0001')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'2','0010')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'3','0011')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'4','0100')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'5','0101')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'6','0110')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'7','0111')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'8','1000')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'9','1001')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'A','1010')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'B','1011')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'C','1100')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'D','1101')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'E','1110')
set @hex=replace (@hex,'F','1111')

RETURN @hex
END

GO
 select 
CASE when col2 IN ('-1', '-9') THEN col2
    ELSE [dbo].[HexToBinary] (col2)
END as val
from
(
    SELECT 'FFF8' as col2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-1' as col2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'FFF6' as col2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '-9' as col2
) a
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a simpler way, but you could use 18 replaces . . .

```
select (case when col2 <> ('-1', '-9')
             then replace(replace(. . . (replace(col2, '0', 'oooo'), '1', 'oool'), . . . ,
                                  'o', '0'), 'l', '1')
             else col2
         end)
```

In other words, replace each hex digit with its equivalent in binary.  This uses `o` for `0` and `1` for `l`.  This prevents one replace from affecting another.

Comment: why not 16 replaces?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev To convert the occurrences of "o" to "0" and "l" to "1".

Comment: ohh, yeah. Didn't thing about that.